# Why does manually programmed deviance and DIC calculated deviance differ in JAGS?

Tags: jags

I am currently fitting a set of 16 models in JAGS. I have a function in jags that calculates the log of the probability of each value of the outcome variable and and another function that takes -2 * the sum of those log probabilities. I.e., I have a custom formula to calculate the deviance for each model. I wanted to check that my definition of the deviance was the same as what JAGS was using.

After running 5000 burnin and 5000 iterations, I obtained the following results:
[image]

Basically, for some models, the deviance was close but not exactly the same, and for other models (e.g., 7, 13, 16) it was vastly different.

**Why is the deviance calculated using my custom formula different to that obtained using the automatic approach based on DIC?**

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of messing around, I think the following is the case.

First, the DIC deviance is obtained using a discrete set of samples to the main parameter estimates. Thus, estimates will differ between runs due to the inherent random aspects of MCMC estimation.

Assuming the chain length is long (several thousand) and burnin is adequate , then differences between the main samples and the DIC samples should be small if the model is converging and reasonably efficient. Thus, big differences are likely to co-occur with model convergence issues.

This all assumes that the original deviance calculation was programmed correctly.